# Add extra labels to a chart

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2016 and wanted to know how I can make a chart that represents a spectrum from left to right with labels on both sides, and a marker in the middle. Essentially I want to represent the [Myers Briggs Type Indicator](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/mbtipresentationeng-130113123038-phpapp01/95/mbti-understanding-self-and-others-18-638.jpg?cb=1424336487).

What I've tried so far is to make a horizontal bar chart with a marker, but I can't seem to get labels to the left and right. How might I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add text boxes from drawing tools and put them on top of the chart. Set their backgrounds to transparent by choosing no fill.